# How do you edit custom class properties in the inspector in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a custom class for some of my sprite nodes. There are some properties like health, size, speed, etc. that I want to be able to modify from the scene inspector. So, when I open GameScene.sks and add a sprite node to the scene and set the custom class I want to be able to change those custom properties. How do I do that?

Comment: No downvote, even though your question lacks everything from code to specifics. In `UIKit` you simply set the custom class and make that custom class `IBDesignable` and maybe `IBInspectble`. Not sure those could work with `SpriteKit`, so I'm not being critical of the lack of details. But maybe it can?

Comment: Marking it as IBDesignable doesn't make it show up in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

not possible in Spritekit, and marking it IBDesignable doesn't work in the Scene editor. You can apply UserData to objects in the Scene Editor but that is not the same.